# How to parse string into an array using set number of characters in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some c# code like this:

```
string myString = "20180426";
```

I know how to parse around specific characters (using the string.Split thing), but how do I get it to return 3 strings like this:

```
2018
04
26
```

I have several strings that are formatted this way ("YYYYMMDD"), so I don't want code that will only work for this specific string. I tried using

```
var finNum = myString[0] + myString[1] + myString[2] + myString[3];
Console.Write(finNum);
```

But I guess it's treating the characters as integers, rather than a text string because it's doing some mathematical operation with them instead of concatenating (it's not addition either because it's returning 203, which isn't the sum of 2, 0, 1 and 8).

I've tried changing `var` to `string`, but it won't let me implicitly convert int to string. Why does it think that `string myString` is an `int`, rather than a `string`, which is what I declared it as?

I could also use `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.ParseExact`, but apparently "20180426" isn't recognized as a valid DateTime:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myString, "YYYYMMDD", null);
Console.WriteLine(myDate);
```

Thank you for your help. I know the answer is probably stupidly easy and I feel dumb for asking but I seriously checked all over various websites and can't find a solution that works for my issue here.

Comment: You used the wrong formatting string. It should be `yyyyMMdd`. `YYYY` and `DD` are *not* recognized as valid format characters, they are treated as string literals

Comment: "but apparently "20180426" isn't recognized as a valid DateTime" insert this char "-" in the string. 2018-04-26 and try to parse with DateTime.Parse again.

Comment: About the interger *transformation*: `var finNum = myString[0] + myString[1] + (...) ;` sums the ASCII values of the corresponding chars. If you add a string transformation (you need to use it just on the first char): `var finNum = myString[0].ToString() + myString[1] + (...) ;` it will switch to string concatenation.

Comment: @Paulo there's nothing wrong with the unseparated format

Comment: As for `var finNum = myString[0] + myString[1] + myString[2] + myString[3];` - `myString[1]` returns a character - if you try to do mathical operations with a char it will calculate the integer representation of the char so your `var finNum` is actually an `int` as you can see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tP9nRU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I could also use `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.ParseExact`, but
>   apparently "20180426" isn't recognized as a valid `DateTime`.

Yes, because the format string `YYYYMMDD` is incorrect, years and days are lowercase:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myString, "yyyyMMdd", null);
```

If you want the year, month and day:

```
int year = myDate.Year;
int month = myDate.Month;
int day = myDate.Day;
```

Comment: DERP I feel really dumb. Thank you so much. By the way, is there a way to return only the first 4 characters of a string or, like characters 5, 6 and 7 of a string? I looked all over the internet and couldn't find that answer, though I'm sure it's out there somewhere.

Comment: @TnD_Guy: Yes, `Substring` you should use. But don't use string methods if you're working with DateTimes. Parse it and then do something with it. As shown in my answer a `DateTime` has also properties to get the month for example.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm very new to programming in general. I'm still not 100% sure what a method is. I've read some tutorials and stuff, but it's a lot of info for someone who has never messed with programming before. I have so much to learn, and I'm getting there, but I've only been doing this for roughly 4 weeks or so. I do appreciate the help, though. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you want year, month and day separated by variables you could try:

```
       string mystring = "20180426";
       mystring = mystring.Insert(4,"-");
       mystring = mystring.Insert(7,"-");

       string year = mystring.Split('-')[0];
       string month = mystring.Split('-')[1];
       string day = mystring.Split('-')[2];
```

1. First I add a character "-" to separate year and month, then another to separate month and day. You get something like "2018-04-26"
2. Then I split the string and save the position 0 that store the first 4 numbers of your string into a variable named year.

Good luck!